# macos: kill process returns no such proceess

Tags: node.js, macos

I am sure I am doing something wrong. But I can't figure what. 
I would like to kill a node process. I identify it with `ps aux | grep node`. Then I execute `kill -9 <processid>`. And I get the above error in the title. Here is a screenshot the problem:

[image]

Why am I getting this error? and how can I kill this process?
Thanks

Comment: You can avoid having the grep command returned by using -v: `ps aux | grep node | grep -v grep`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like node is running from the image you've posted. In the image you've linked, `pid` 2371 is not that of `node` but of `grep`. You can confirm this by providing some rubbish pattern to `grep` say:

```
ps aux | grep blahbleh
// outputs pid 2354
user           2354   0.0 grep blahbleh
```

Notice the `command` is `grep blahbleh`. Search for command which starts with `node`